# Update a column values from another df where ids are same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe like below

**df1**:

```
article_id col1  col2
1            2   2.5
2            5   2.5
3            3   2.5
4            8   2.5
5            2   2.5
6            5   2.5
7            1   2.5
```

**df2**:

```
article_id somecol3   
30           11       
6            3
22           1 
5            4 
3            7
61           8 
7            3
```

`article_id` of both df1 and df2 are unique. Both df1 and df2 has some common`article_id`, in above (6,5,3,7). What I want is that, **update** the values of somecol3 of df2 from values of column col1 of df1 where the 'article_id's are common. So the df2 should look like this after the operation

```
article_id somecol3   
30            11
6             5
22            1
5             2
3             3
61            8
7             1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df2['somecol3'] = (df2['article_id'].map(df1.set_index('article_id')['col1'])
                                    .combine_first(df2['somecol3'])
                                    .astype(int))
print (df2)

   article_id  somecol3
0          30        11
1           6         5
2          22         1
3           5         2
4           3         3
5          61         8
6           7         1
```

---

```
df2['somecol3'] = (df2['article_id'].map(df1.set_index('article_id')['col1'])
                                    .fillna(df2['somecol3'])
                                    .astype(int))
print (df2)
   article_id  somecol3
0          30        11
1           6         5
2          22         1
3           5         2
4           3         3
5          61         8
6           7         1
```

Solution with [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html):

```
df2['somecol3'].update(df2['article_id'].map(df1.set_index('article_id')['col1']))
print (df2)
   article_id  somecol3
0          30        11
1           6         5
2          22         1
3           5         2
4           3         3
5          61         8
6           7         1
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Could you please update the answer according to my updated question?

Comment: Sure, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

By using `merge`

```
 df1.merge(df[['article_id','col1']],on='article_id',how='left').fillna('')
    Out[48]: 
       article_id col1
    0          30     
    1           6    5
    2          22     
    3           5    2
    4           3    3
    5          61     
    6           7    1
```

Updated

```
df2.merge(df1[['article_id', 'col1']], on='article_id', how='left').ffill(1).drop('somecol3',1)
Out[69]: 
   article_id  col1
0        30.0  11.0
1         6.0   5.0
2        22.0   1.0
3         5.0   2.0
4         3.0   3.0
5        61.0   8.0
6         7.0   1.0
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Could you please update the answer according to my updated question?